# How can I consider given date in string format as est and convert it to utc in java?

Tags: java, date

I have a date in the string format
`String date = "2021-04-26 08:28:56 "`

Now, I want to consider this as an EST Date and convert it into UTC.

The UTC for this would be
`"2021-04-25 10:58:56"`

So,

**Input :**

2021-04-26 08:28:56

**Output :**

2021-04-25 10:58:56

How can I do this in Java ?

Comment: There are several time zones that can be abbreviated EST all or some of the year. Which one do you mean? Apparently you think that your EST is 21 hours 30 minutes ahead of UTC, but no such time zone can exist. Please double-check what would be the correct conversion.

Comment: What did you search turn up? Very similar questions have been asked and answered countless times.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```java
LocalDateTime
.parse(
    "2021-04-26 08:28:56"
    .replace( " " , "T" )
)
.atZone(
    ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" )
)
.toInstant()
.toString()
.replace( "T" , " " )
.replace( "Z" , "" )
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/x18ktQ).

> 2021-04-26 12:28:56

Your expected result is incorrect. If by `EST` you meant a time zone such as `America/New_York`, that zone at that moment is **four hours behind UTC**. So to get from 8 AM you must *add* 4 hours, to get 12 noon rather than your expected 10 AM hour on the previous date.

## Details

Parse your input as a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) because it lacks an indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC. We convert your input to comply with ISO 8601 by replacing the SPACE in the middle with a `T`.

A `LocalDateTime` does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. This class represents only a date and time-of-day. Without the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC, we do not know what clock where strikes that time.

You claim to know this string was intended to represent a date-time as seen in `EST`. Unfortunately, `EST` is not a [real time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Did you mean east coast time of North America, such as `America/New_York`? If so, your expected output is incorrect.

If so, obtain a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) for that time zone. Apply the time zone to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). Now we have defined a moment, a specific point on the timeline.

You want to see the same moment in UTC. One easy way to adjust to UTC is to simply extract an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) from our `ZonedDateTime` object. An `Instant` object is always in UTC, by definition.

Your desired output is similar to the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format used by default in the `toString` method of `Instant`. Just remove the `T` from between the date and the time-of-day, and remove the `Z` at the end that represents an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds. By the way, I suggest *not* removing the `Z` to make the meaning crystal clear. Removing the `Z` introduces ambiguity.

```java
String input = "2021-04-26 08:28:56".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;  // Adjust to UTC by extracting an `Instant` object. `Instant` is always in UTC, by definition.
String output = instant.toString().replace( "T" , " " ).replace( "Z" , "" ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).